# Where is Selective Sync option on latest Dropbox?

Tags: windows-10, dropbox

On Windows, Dropbox used to have "Selective Sync..." settings under [Windows Tray / Dropbox icon / "Gear" icon / Preferences...,
then "Account" tab.

I don't see it any more?  (Windows 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows 10, it has moved to "Sync" tab - the last tab in "Preferences" dialog.